# Função com ponteiro para ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Tenho a seguinte função

**NOTA:** Nesta função está apenas o primeiro caso, para não ficar muito grande. Já que o erro se dá logo na primeira inserção.

```
int insertAVL_TreeR(struct AVL_TreeNode **node, void *elem, int *h) {
        if (!node) {//se o nó não existir, é criado um novo no
            AVL_TreeNode *novo = (AVL_TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof (AVL_TreeNode));
            novo->elem = elem;
            novo->fb = 0;
            novo->left = NULL;
            novo->right = NULL;
            node = novo;
            *h = 1; //haverá mudança na altura
        } else {
```

Que é chamada dentro destra função

```
int insertAVL_Tree(struct AVL_Tree *tree, void *elem) {
    if (!tree)return 0;
    int *h = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int));
    *h = 1;
    AVL_TreeNode **p = &tree->root;
    int x = insertAVL_TreeR(*p, elem, h); //a chamada se dá nesta linha
    return x;
}
```

Quero saber como é a maneira correto de passar este ponteiro para ponteiro. Pois dentro da função recebo um warning e corre tudo bem, mas quando volta para o main, a avl->root(previamente inicializada como NULL) segue apontando pra NULL.

Minhas structs são esssa

```
typedef struct AVL_TreeNode
{
  void *elem;
  struct AVL_TreeNode *left;
  struct AVL_TreeNode *right;
  int fb;
}AVL_TreeNode;
```

e

```
typedef struct AVL_Tree 
{
  struct AVL_TreeNode *root;
}AVL_Tree;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chamada que do método `insertAVL_TreeR` está errada, o parâmetro node é um ponteiro duplo, que seria sua variável `AVL_TreeNode **p`. e ao chamar o método, você envia como parâmetro o endereço de memória que está dentro de `p`.
O correto seria passar o `p` sem o `*`, pois assim passaria o endereço de memória que tem a referencia do seu `tree->root`. Ficando assim:

```
int x = insertAVL_TreeR(p, elem, h);
```

Agora no seu método de `insertAVL_TreeR` o erro está onde você atribui o valor para `node`. `node` é uma variável independente que armazena um endereço de memória, atribuir algum valor à ela, não vai mudar em nada o nó da sua arvore, então como fazer? Sabe-se que o valor de `node` é o endereço que armazena o seu nó, então você precisa alterar o valor de dentro do node dessa forma.

```
(*node) = novo;

/*
node = <Endereço de tree->root>
(*node) = tree->root
*/
```

Dessa forma você consegue alterar o valor de seu nó.